# How to convert array to object without keys on aggregation query of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query result like this;

```
{
    "content" : [
        "X",
        "1"
    ]
}
```

And my query is like that;

```
db.getCollection("x").aggregate([
{$group : {_id : null, tN: {$addToSet : { content: [ "$tN", "$pC" ] }}}},
{$unwind: "$tN"},
{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$tN'}}
])
```

How can I convert that **content** array into;

```
{
    "tN" : "X",
    "pC" : "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) within [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) stage

```
db.getCollection("x").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      tN: { $addToSet: { content: [ "$tN", "$pC" ] } }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tN"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$tN" }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "tN": {
        $arrayElemAt: [ "$content", 0 ]
      },
      "pC": {
        $arrayElemAt: [ "$content", 1 ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E_b5ou2_qWP)